# Where does the energy of a redshifted photon go to?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, space-expansion, redshift

When traveling through the vacuum, electromagnetic waves experience an increase of wavelength (redshift).

According to this equation:

$$E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}=h\nu$$

( Where, as we know, h is the Plank constant, c is the light speed, λ is the wavelenght and ν is the frequency of the wave. )

An increment of the wavelength implies a decrement of the energy of the photon.

The question is, where does that energy go? Is it consumed during millions of years of movement of the EM or is there another explanation?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 4) If you get a satisfactory answer, remember to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267186

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A question on the redshift of photons due to cosmic expansion](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267186/)

Comment: This one is possibly the earliest, clearest duplicate : [Redshifted Photon Energy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4821)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redshifted Photon Energy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4821/)